# Best practice UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

i'm experiencing a memory problem when using a uiscrollview in iOS.

I have a scrollview with a huge subview (4000x600).
Into this subview, i have other UIImageViews as subviews.

This is the case:

[image: Test]

When i open the scrollview, i can see both memory and process increasing dramatically.

What i want to know to fix the problem is: 
is it better to add all my views directly to scrollview, without passing to a "middle" huge view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your many subviews are added directly as subviews of the scroll view or a single large container view. As long as they are all added together, they remain loaded in memory and waste resources. Instead, you should add and remove these subviews dynamically as the user scrolls left and right.

Instead of inventing the wheel, use a `UICollectionView`. It is meant to accomplish exactly what you need. Each image view will then be a cell in that collection view. The collection view manages view reuse and only holds in memory the necessary cells for display around the scroll position.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Comment: The only thing I'd add is to make sure you're loading images a-synchronously on a separate thread.